# Catching the complexity of determining some recursively defined property

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, complexity-classes, property-testing

I am currently working on some property defined in the following way. Let $S$ be a set of positive integers. We say that $S$ has the property $P$ iff one of the following two conditions holds.

1. This set $S$ is a singleton.
2. For every $x \in \{1,…,\lfloor \frac{|S|}{2} \rfloor\}$, there exists a partition of $S$ into two parts $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that their sizes are $x$ and $|S|-x$, respectively, and they both satisfy the property $P$.

In other words, $S$ has the property $P$ iff it can always be partitioned into two subsets of arbitrary sizes having the property $P$ themselves.

Now, I would like to consider the complexity of the associated decision problem.

> P-PROPERTY
>
> Instance: A set $S$ of positive integers.
>
> Question: Does $S$ have the property $P$?

At first sight, such a problem belongs neither to NP nor to co-NP (does it?). Moreover, because of the recursivity, I do not see how this problem could belong to the polynomial hierarchy.

I never saw a problem recursively defined like this one, that is why I am getting some trouble dealing with it. So, is there a way to deal with the complexity of such a problem?

Thanks in advance (and sorry if the answer is obvious :o) )!

Comment: Condition 2 does not seem to be equivalent to the sentence _"$S$ has the property $P$ if and only if it can always be partitioned into 2 subsets of arbitrary sizes having the property $P$ themselves"_. Condition 2 says $\forall x$..., while the above sentence seems to say $\exists x$...

Comment: If the answer is that there only has to be one partition at each level (rather than for every partition) with described conditions, and property $P$ is PTIME decidable, then the problem should be in NP. We can ask for a certificate that's something along the lines of "label each element with a string over $\{1,2\}$, which gives which partite set it is in at that recursive depth". Then we can check that the partitions satisfy $P$ easily enough.

Comment: In the other case, it should be in co-NP, as we can give a short certificate for a No-instances (i.e. one partition that doesn't have the property $P$).

Comment: Every finite set has property $P$ (prove it by induction). If $S$ is infinite then your definition doesn't really make sense (for several reasons), so I presume the domain you were looking at was finite sets, and for that domain, every set has property $P$.

Comment: Of course! Too busy thinking about complexity, not enough about the actual property.

Comment: Well, I tried to give an overview of the property using sets to show off its recursive aspect, but the problem I am actually working on deals with graphs. 

A graph G is said to be R-AP (recursively arbitrarily partitionable) iff one of the two conditions holds.

1. The graph is an isolated vertex.
2. For every $x \in \{1, ..., \lfloor \frac{|V(G)|}{2} \rfloor \}$ there exists a partition $(V_1, V_2)$ of $V(G)$ such that $G[V_1]$ and $G[V_2]$ are connected R-AP graphs on $x$ and $n-x$ vertices, respectively.

Does it seem to be that easy when considering graphs instead of sets?

Comment: Just because the definition is recursive doesn't mean that this problem is not in NP (or even P). Pratt first showed that PRIMES is in NP by a recursive process now known as the [Pratt certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate#Pratt_certificates) that I think sounds similar to your problem.

Comment: @Tyson Naively, the witness is superpolynomial in size, probably $n^{\log n}$.

Comment: @jbensmai, you should rephrase your question, and add links to relevant papers (to motivate the notion, at the very least).